# Can you echo PHP inside a PHP echo tag avoiding apostrophes?

Tags: php

The problem I am facing is that only the 'rr_pos_1' tags in
    `<?php if (isset($_POST['rr_pos_1']) ? $_POST['rr_pos_1'] : null) echo "$rr_pos_1"; ?>`are outputting a php error due to the apostrophes ('). Is there anyway I can avoid that error by using the same method of print below?

Here's my php code:

```
<?php
switch (isset($_POST['chk']) ? $_POST['chk'] : null){
    case 'Rigid Rail':
        echo '
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Notes & Comments: <?php if (isset($_POST['rr_pos_1']) ? $_POST['rr_pos_1'] : null) echo "$rr_pos_1"; ?></th>
            </tr>
        </table>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Your `if` inside the case is wrong, if the `post` is set then you're checking it as a `boolean`, otherwise you're checking `null` as a `boolean`, which is weird.

Comment: Ternaries inside conditionals are hard to read, further compounded by your ternaries returning `null`. Just make them straight `if` statements using `empty`, e.g., `if (!empty($_POST['rr_pos_1']))`

Comment: Are you trying to echo out the literal php string `<?php if ... ?>` or just the variable `$rr_pos_1`? You are already within php tags when trying to echo another set of php tags. `<?=` is for use when not inside php tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <?php switch (isset($_POST['chk']) ? $_POST['chk'] : null){
   case 'Rigid Rail': ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
     <td>Notes & Comments: 
      <?php echo (isset($_POST['rr_pos_1'])) ? $_POST['rr_pos_1'] : null; ?>
     </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <?php break; }?>
```

Yep, just don't put it inside the PHP tags.

Comment: Ah! That works like a charm! Didn't know that you could break php that way! Cheers mate!

Comment: No worries - remember to mark the answer as your chosen one :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax or end php interpreting after the case:

```
switch ($a) {
case "foo":  ?>
   bla bla html <?php echo $a ?> 
<?php break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also slightly edit your own code;

I wish to slightly edit the code myself, since I believe the check should be done before the switch and checked it exists

```
<?php
// Check the value exists
$value = (array_key_exists('chk', $_POST) && is_string($_POST['chk']) && !empty($_POST['chk'])) 
       ? $_POST['chk'] : FALSE ;

// Check it passed and holds a value
if ($value)
{
    // Now you know it exists, use the switch
    switch ($value) 
    {
        case "Rigid Rail":
            echo '
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    Notes & Comments: 
                    ' . ( isset($_POST['rr_pos_1']) ? $_POST['rr_pos_1'] : '' ) . '
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: First line can be reduced to: `$value = !empty($_POST['chk']) ? $_POST['chk'] : FALSE;`

Comment: Almost, but since you need to check that the input is a string, as it will be used for the switch() it's better to do that before someone sends data cross-site which includes checkboxes with the name of "chk[]" just to be a pain in your ass :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any need for ternary operator for isset

```
<?php
switch (isset($_POST['chk'])){
case 'Rigid Rail':
    ?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Notes & Comments: <?php if (isset($_POST['rr_pos_1'])) echo "$rr_pos_1"; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: If you use `isset` in the switch your cases will only match booleans (casted from string).

Comment: got it. but certainly not required for second isset.

Comment: The reason that the ternary operator is present is because it is echoing data from the previous page. If that data is not checked, it won't show up here. Which is why I ran into this problem in the first place. But I get it. Different methods of accomplish the same goal.